# Validity of "rank" construction in Manin's proof of Lemma 6.7 for Gödel's completeness theorem

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, proof-theory

The question is about the proof of Lemma 6.7 in Yuri Manin's "A Course in Mathematical Logic", which is part of the proof of Gödel's completeness theorem.

> **Lemma 6.7** If $\mathcal{E}$ is consistent and contains $\text{Ax }L$, then there exist:
>   (a) a language $L'$ whose alphabet is obtained from the alphabet of $L$ by adding a set of new constants having cardinality $\leq$ card (alphabet of $L$) + $\aleph_0$.
>   (b) a set of formulas $\mathcal{E'}$ in $L'$ which is consistent, contains $\mathcal{E}$ and $\text{Ax }L'$, and has the property that the alphabet of $L'$ is sufficient for $\mathcal{E'}$.

Part (a) of the claim is proven by simply adding to the alphabet of $L$ a set of new constants of cardinality card (alphabet of L) + $\aleph_0$, and creating a new language $L'$ using this alphabet. The proof then shows that $\mathcal{E} \cup \text{Ax }L$ is consistent, and I am okay with this part.

---

This particular section of the proof is confusing:

> (c) We consider the set $S$ of formulas $P(x)$ containing one free variable $x$ and such that $\neg\forall x P(x) \in \mathcal{E} \cup \text{Ax }L'$. For each $P(x)$ in $S$ we choose a new constant $c_P$ subject to the following restriction: each $c_P$ can be assigned a natural number, its rank, in such a way that if a constant of rank $n$ occurs in $P(x)$ then $c_P$ has rank $\gt n$.

The set $\text{Ax }L'$ consists of the tautologies of $L'$ and logical quantifier axioms. But a proposition of the form $\neg\forall x P(x)$ cannot be either of those.

It cannot be a tautology because tautologies are logical polynomials over a finite set of base propositions, whose truth value is $1$ independently of the choice of truth value for each base proposition (section 3.4). Since $\neg\forall x P(x)$ contains only a single connective $\neg$ (quantifiers cannot show up as connectives), either $\neg\forall x P(x)$ or $\forall x P(x)$ must be the base proposition, and clearly in both cases the truth value is dependent on the truth value of the base proposition.

The formula $\neg\forall x P(x)$ cannot either be a logical quantifier axiom because the quantifier axioms have one of the following structures, none of which fit the structure of $\neg\forall x P(x)$ (section 3.5):

(a) $\forall x (P \implies Q) \implies (P \implies \forall x Q)$
(b) $\forall x \neg P \iff \neg \exists x P$
(c) $\forall x P(x) \implies P(t)$

Therefore we must have "$\neg\forall x P(x)$" $\in \mathcal{E}$. But in that case, there cannot be any new constants $c_P$ of $L'$ contained in that formula since it lies in the original language $L$ which does not have this extended alphabet.

With that reasoning, it would seem that the rank of $c_P$ can always be chosen as $1$, because there are no constants of rank $\geq 1$ contained in $P(x)$. So the notion of "rank" seems to be useless for the proof.

Did I miss something which makes it essential to introduce the rank, or can the proof carry on without it?

Comment: The construction is a little bit convoluted... You have to start from a formula of the basic language (and thus - as you said - without "added" constant $c_p$) and then add the new formula. As long as you have done this, you have generated a lot of new formulas (in the language extended with $c_p$) and thus you have to iterate the process.

Comment: I am not exactly sure where the iteration occurs. In Lemma 6.7 all the new formulas that are created after adding $c_P$ are either tautologies, quantifier axioms, or formulas of the type $R_P: \neg\forall x P(x) \implies \neg P(c_P)$. None of these will generate new formulas of the form $\neg\forall x P(x)$ to which we could apply the process again, except those that were already in $L$.

Comment: I think there is some sort of iteration happening in Lemma 6.8 in order to make the set both complete and have sufficient alphabet, but that doesn't seem to be for the same reasons.

Comment: Maybe I would need to see a specific example of a case where you would need $c_P$ with rank $\geq 2$.

Comment: Maybe we can check on [Henkin's original proof](https://users.fit.cvut.cz/~staryja2/BIALO/henkin-the-completeness-of-the-first-order-calculus.pdf).

Comment: So I've had a look at Henkin's proof of the THEOREM (p. 162). It seems that he is basically combining the Lemmas 6.6, 6.7 and 6.8 in Manin in the same proof (of course Manin actually adapted Henkin's proof, not the other way around, but I mean that the argument is of this form). So in Henkin's proof all the constants are labeled $u_{i,j}$ to indicate which level of iteration they are added in. I suppose Manin's concept of rank corresponds to the index $i$ in Henkin's notation.

Comment: In Manin's proof, Lemma 6.7 exists in its own separate context, which is a single step of the iteration. So I think the rank is not completely necessary, as in a single step of the iteration all added constants will have the same rank (or same index $i$ as in Henkin's proof).

Comment: You are right; the "iteration" is needed only for Lemma 6.8.

Comment: And I think you are right in general; in the first step (described in Lemma 6.7) only constant of rank 1 will be used, because no such constant is present in the basic language. The rank "mechanism" is needed only when iterating the procedure to build the maximal consistent set of sentences.